# Apple Watch Complication Tint Color

Tags: apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

I'm trying to add a tint color to a Complication Template image. When I'm scrolling through the options to customize my watch face, the tint color is correct. However, once I select the complication and return to the normal watch face state, the color switches back to white.

```
- (void)getLocalizableSampleTemplateForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(CLKComplicationTemplate * __nullable complicationTemplate))handler {
  CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallSimpleImage *modularTemplate = [[CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallSimpleImage alloc] init];
  CLKImageProvider *imageProvider = [CLKImageProvider imageProviderWithOnePieceImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Complication/Modular"]];
  imageProvider.tintColor  = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.412 green:0.443 blue:0.773 alpha:1.000];
  modularTemplate.imageProvider = imageProvider;
  handler(modularTemplate);
}
```

Customizing:
[Tint is correct while customizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmeVf.png)

After complication is selected:
[Tint is gone and it's back to a white image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMiGx.png)

Comment: The function in your question only takes care of the __template__ which is shown when selecting a complication. You need to replicate the same behaviour in your functions preparing the actual complication data.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thank you. That did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

As David mentioned in the comments, the function in the question only takes care of the **template** and you need to replicate the same behavior in your functions preparing the actual complication data.

Add the following code to make the tint color persist past the selection phase:

```
- (void)getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(CLKComplicationTimelineEntry * __nullable))handler {
  CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallSimpleImage *template = [[CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallSimpleImage alloc] init];
  CLKImageProvider *imageProvider = [CLKImageProvider imageProviderWithOnePieceImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Complication/Modular"]];
  imageProvider.tintColor  = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.412 green:0.443 blue:0.773 alpha:1.000];
  template.imageProvider = imageProvider;
  handler([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry entryWithDate:[NSDate date] complicationTemplate:template]);
}
```